# Events dataLayer.push code in Google tag manager wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I implemented GA4 using Google tag manager in wordpress without using plugin.But I don't where to add the dataLayer.push code for events like view_item_list, view_item, add_to_cart, remove_from_cart, view_cart.

Please say where to add the dataLayer.push code for these events. It will be useful for me if anybody shows the script with dynamic values.